# Laravel ! QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: select * from student). What does this driver refer to?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I put Laravel file in xammp/htdocs and I want to connect to Postgresql, but I still got the error that the drive could not find. Do I need to find a driver or another thing wrong in my Laravel file?

Comment: Have you told laravel to use postgres in your .env file?

Comment: I have changed for using Postgres in .env file and config/database already.

Comment: Can you show your .env database config file in your question please

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=1234

Comment: @Petay87 Thanks for your responding. I've solved it already by changing php.ini in my wamp server in order to enable PDO for its driver.

Answer (score 1):

---

Hello,

Open your php.ini: to verify what file is loaded: terminal: php --init
Uncomment the line with PDO.
Restart server